# Pull Artifacts from Nexus into XL Deploy

Tags: nexus, xl-deploy

We have XLDeploy being used to deploy application. We do not want to use default feature where Nexus pushes new XL deploy whenever it get new artifacts. On the need basis we want to pull the artifacts from Nexus into XL Deploy. What are the steps?

Answer (score 0):

You will need first to [Configure XL Deploy to fetch artifacts from a repository](https://docs.xebialabs.com/xl-deploy/how-to/configure-xl-deploy-to-fetch-artifacts-from-a-maven-repository.html), Then you can [add an externally stored artifact to a package](https://docs.xebialabs.com/xl-deploy/how-to/add-an-externally-stored-artifact-to-a-package.html) .. You may also have a look on this tutorial [deploy an externally stored artifact using the cli](https://docs.xebialabs.com/xl-deploy/how-to/deploy-an-externally-stored-artifact-using-the-cli.html) which will show you how to use the XL Deploy (CLI) to deploy an artifact from a Maven repository such as Artifactory or Nexus.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the XLRelease and give the configuration details with Nexus repository. That will help you out!